# Where does ownCloud save data on my hosting?

Tags: ftp, cloud, web-hosting, cloud-hosting

I have installed ownCloud on my hosting and uploaded some documents.

Where can I find the uploaded documents on my hosting (e.g. via FTP)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the question. Answer is `/www_root/DOMAIN/owncloud/data/NAME/files` when I was looking for it I did not updated data.